# changing folder ownership, operation permitted, also as root

Tags: debian, chown

I have 2 moxa computers (Debian 9) with both an SD card installed.
the problem is with one computer's SD card mounting. 
I can not change group ownerships

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sd-mmcblk0p1 vfat rw,relatime,gid=100,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

`ls -al` of the folder;

```
root@AAGCloudwatcher:/media/sd-mmcblk0p1# ls -al
total 129
drwxrwxr-x 5 root users 32768 Sep  8 20:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1024 Sep  7 22:32 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 root users 32768 Jul 15 21:15 config
drwxrwxr-x 7 root users 32768 Sep  7 19:13 data
drwxrwxr-x 2 root users 32768 Sep  7 19:44 tmp
```

I want to read and write files from one moxa computer on the other. 
With samba i managed to access the folder, and review the data. But not writing. 
Now i noticed that the ownership of the group is differently. 
Now the ownerships are root:users

```
SOLO@AAGCloudwatcher:/media/sd-mmcblk0p1$ sudo chown SOLO:SOLO data
chown: changing ownership of 'data': Operation not permitted
```

I googled a lot: the mounted drive is FAT32, the folders are update with 777 read / wright permission. I have one other computer with also SD card mounted and had the same problem that i cant write with another moxa pc and sd card. I then did the same and that worked like a charm.When the ownerships are changed i will be able to communicate and write in that folder. 
Important: i can write in the folder, when working form the local MOXA computer.

`chgrp`does also not work.

lsattr gives me this:

```
    root@AAGCloudwatcher:/media/sd-mmcblk0p1# lsattr
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./data
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./config
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./tmp
```

`cat /proc/mounts` gives me this

```
    /dev/root / ext4 rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=247604k,nr_inodes=61901,mode=755 0 0
/dev/mmcblk1p3 /overlayfs ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
overlay /var overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//var_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//var_rw/work 0 0
overlay /etc overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//etc_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//etc_rw/work 0 0
overlay /home overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/home,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//home_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//home_rw/work 0 0
overlay /root overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/root,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//root_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//root_rw/work 0 0
overlay /sbin overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/sbin,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//sbin_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//sbin_rw/work 0 0
overlay /bin overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/bin,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//bin_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//bin_rw/work 0 0
overlay /usr overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/usr,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//usr_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//usr_rw/work 0 0
overlay /lib overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/lib,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//lib_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//lib_rw/work 0 0
overlay /tmp overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/tmp,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//tmp_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//tmp_rw/work 0 0
overlay /mnt overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/mnt,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//mnt_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//mnt_rw/work 0 0
overlay /opt overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/opt,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//opt_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//opt_rw/work 0 0
overlay /media overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/media,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//media_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//media_rw/work 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sd-mmcblk0p1 vfat rw,relatime,gid=100,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1001 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=51180k,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0
```

What i expect is to get the folders ownerships like this and then i think my problem is solved.

```
root@AAGCloudwatcher:/media/sd-mmcblk0p1# ls -al
total 129
drwxrwxr-x 5 root users 32768 Sep  8 20:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1024 Sep  7 22:32 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 SOLO SOLO 32768 Jul 15 21:15 config
drwxrwxr-x 7 SOLO SOLO 32768 Sep  7 19:13 data
drwxrwxr-x 2 SOLO SOLO 32768 Sep  7 19:44 tmp
```

Thank you.

UPDATE: the output of mount:

```
root@AAGCloudwatcher:/home/SOLO# mount
/dev/mmcblk1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=247604k,nr_inodes=61901,mode=755)
/dev/mmcblk1p3 on /overlayfs type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
overlay on /var type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//var_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//var_rw/work)
overlay on /etc type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//etc_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//etc_rw/work)
overlay on /home type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/home,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//home_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//home_rw/work)
overlay on /root type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/root,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//root_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//root_rw/work)
overlay on /sbin type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/sbin,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//sbin_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//sbin_rw/work)
overlay on /bin type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/bin,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//bin_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//bin_rw/work)
overlay on /usr type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/usr,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//usr_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//usr_rw/work)
overlay on /lib type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/lib,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//lib_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//lib_rw/work)
overlay on /tmp type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/tmp,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//tmp_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//tmp_rw/work)
overlay on /mnt type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/mnt,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//mnt_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//mnt_rw/work)
overlay on /opt type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/opt,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//opt_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//opt_rw/work)
overlay on /media type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/media,upperdir=/overlayfs/v1//media_rw/upper,workdir=/overlayfs/v1//media_rw/work)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/

fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
    systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
    mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
    debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
    configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
    /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/sd-mmcblk0p1 type vfat (rw,relatime,gid=100,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
    tmpfs on /run/user/1001 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=51180k,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=1001)
    binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

fcheck gives me this:

```
root@AAGCloudwatcher:/home/SOLO# fsck /media/sd-mmcblk0p1/
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
fsck.ext2: Is a directory while trying to open /media/sd-mmcblk0p1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: Have you tried fsck on the filesystem? The > Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./data seems to indicate something's wrong. Addittionaly please post the output from "mount".

Comment: I think your problem is more related to the fact you are using fat32, this kind of filesystem was not originally projected to have owners to files or folders, if you need to have this on in this kind of filesystem, use a tar.gz file to store your data, or reformat it with ext4 or with some linux filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

@luciano-andress-martini in the comments is correct: the problem is that the FAT32 file system does not support unix user and group ownerships nor access permissions.

As a result all files and directories on that file system will have the same owner and group and changing them with `chown`/`chgrp` is not possible. You can however specify the owner and group as well as the `umask`/permissions for all files as mount options:

```
mount -o uid=SOLO,gid=SOLO /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sd-mmcblk0p1
```

You can specify these manually when mounting or permanently configure them in `/etc/fstab`. See all the [vfat mount options](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfat.txt).